# Is there a proof for why the acceleration of an object undergoing simple harmonic motion related to angular velocity squared?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator

Many textbook says the defining equation of the acceleration of an object undergoing simple harmonic motion is $$a= -\omega^2 \times x.$$

Is there a reason as to why acceleration is related to $\omega^2$?

Comment: Dimensional analysis?

Comment: The same symbol $\omega$ is used quite often for both angular velocity and frequency. There is no need to think about angular velocity when you meet simple harmonic motion.

Comment: Yes, the two $\omega$ quantities arise from the second derivative of $x$, since $x=X \sin( \omega t)$ contains an $\omega t$ term.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason as to why acceleration is related to $\omega^2$?

For simple harmonic motion in one-dimension, the motion is of the form

$$x(t) = x_0\cos\omega t + \frac{v_0}{\omega}\sin\omega t$$

where $x_0$ and $v_0$ are the initial position and initial velocity respectively.  The motion is periodic with time $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

The acceleration is easily found to be

$$\ddot x(t) =  -\omega^2x_0\cos\omega t -\omega^2\frac{v_0}{\omega}\sin\omega t = -\omega^2 x(t)$$

Note that one could easily write the differential equation with a non-squared coefficient instead.  For example,

$$\ddot x(t) =  -\frac{k}{m}x(t)$$

and then the motion is written as

$$x(t) = x_0\cos \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t + \frac{v_0}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}\sin\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t$$

It's easy now to see why $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$ is often seen.

Answer (score 1):

A body undergoes simple harmonic motion if the acceleration of the body is proportional to the distance of the body from a fixed point and the acceleration is always directed towards the fixed point is one way of defining simple harmonic motion.

$a\, \hat x\propto -x\, \hat x$

Now the constant of proportionality needs to be introduced and $\omega^2$ is chosen because it is positive and related to the period of the motion $T=\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}$

$a\, \hat x= \omega ^2(-x)\, \hat x \Rightarrow a= -\omega ^2\,x$